# How to read text from an application automated using pywinauto

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation

```
appx = None
appx = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'putty -ssh etc etc')
putty = appx.PuTTY
time.sleep(4) # a captcha question loads (4+2), I need to get the output in ssh shell
print(appx.child_window())
timer.sleep(10)
putty.type_keys ("{ENTER}")
```

I want to get whatever is displayed on the screen,so I can split and get the captcha

Comment: Are you sure you want to use pywinauto for this?  If you're automating putty it seems like you should be using https://www.paramiko.org/ or something like that.